# Updating df with for loop

Tags: python

I have this df

```
    Var     Zip
0   x   803020
1   y   80302
2   z   803098
```

I am Applying this for loop and the df is not changing even though I am not getting an error

```
for x in df['Zip']:
    y = len(x)
    if y == 6:
         x = x[:-1]
            
print(df)
```

Output

```
    Var     Zip
0   x   803020
1   y   80302
2   z   803098
```

Desired Output

```
    Var     Zip
0   x   80302
1   y   80302
2   z   80309
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `df.apply` like this example:

```
df['Zip'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: row['Zip'][:-1] if len(row['Zip']) == 6 else row['Zip'],
    axis=1
)

print(df)

  Var    Zip
0   x  80302
1   y  80302
2   z  80309
```

**PS:** I'm supposing that `Zip` column is marked as `str`. If not you can convert it to `str` like this:

```
df['Zip'] = df['Zip'].astype(str)
```

**Edit:**

If you need a faster approach you could use:

```
df['Zip'] = df['Zip'].apply(lambda row: row[:-1] if len(row) == 6 else row)
```

And here is some benchmarks:

```
In [1]: %timeit df['Zip'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Zip'][:-1] if len(row['Zip']) == 6 else row['Zip'], axis=1)                                                                                                  
714 µs ± 18.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [2]: %timeit df['Zip'] = df['Zip'].apply(lambda row: row[:-1] if len(row) == 6 else row)                                                                                                                                
274 µs ± 3.62 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Note that by utilizing `axis = 1 ` this is a far slower solution than utilizing the `apply` on just the series.

Comment: @WolVes Yes you're right. I've updated my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This does not follow best practices. You should utilize `df.apply` for something like this:

```
df['Zip'] = df['Zip'].apply(lambda x: x[:-1] if len(x) == 6 else x)
```

If your column is an int and needs to remain an int, this also works:

```
df['Zip'] = df['Zip'].apply(lambda x: int(str(x)[:-1]) if len(str(x)) == 6 else x)
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to modify the `Zip` column not creating another column. Also, converting a column to str can be done easly by `df['Zip'] = df['Zip'].astype(str)`

Comment: oof, have to tell you best practices but miss the mark over not capitalizing a column. That is actually painful.

Comment: @ChihebNexus, That was kind of you. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You are simply creating a variable x which is the string-slice of the cell value, you're not doing anything with it.

Try this.

```
for n in range(len(df['Zip'])):
    y = len(df['Zip'][n])
    if y == 6:
         df['Zip'][n] = df['Zip'][n][:-1]
```